# Nodejs runs but did not output 'Hello' (using module)

Tags: javascript, node.js

server.js runs with no error message, still in the browser http://localhost:1337 stays blank instead of 'Hello Node.js' why ?

server.js :

```
var hello = require('./hello');

var http = require('http');
var ipaddress = '127.0.0.1';
var port = 1337;

var server = http.createServer(hello.onRequest);
server.listen(port, ipaddress);
```

hello.js :

```
exports.module = {

    hello: function (req, res) {
        res.end('Hello Node.js');
    }
  ,
    onRequest: function (req, res) {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
        hello (req, res)
    }

}
```

Comment: and... `hello(req, res)` doesn't throw an error? ah, *because it never gets called.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have your export backwards.

It's `module.exports`, not `exports.module`.

```
module.exports = {

    hello: function (req, res) {
        res.end('Hello Node.js');
    },
    onRequest: function (req, res) {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
        hello (req, res)
    }

}
```

In addition, hello won't be defined in that context, so instead, you'll need to define it somewhere where onRequest can access it. A simple suggested refactoring would be exporting named functions declared earlier in the code.

```
function hello(req, res) {
    res.end('Hello Node.js');
}

function onRequest(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    hello(req, res)
}

module.exports = {
    hello: hello,
    onRequest: onRequest
}
```

Comment: I have a subsequent question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38753143/this-hello-is-not-a-function-in-nodejs-exports-module